# c# WPF UI hangs while Update data in UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

UI freeze for 3-10 seconds while update data in UI thread I want to update data in UI thread without freeze.

Code:

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // Get data from Server
    GetData(true);
});
```

Inside `Getdata()`

```
//Converst JSON to DataSet Object:- "tempDataSet"
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{             
    RetriveData(tempDataSet, firstTime);
}, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, MainFrame.Current);
```

Inside `RetriveData`

```
DataTable response  = tempDataSet.Tables["response"];
DataTable conversations = tempDataSet.Tables["convo"];

foreach (DataRow row in conversations.Rows) // UI Hangs in the method
 {
    UC_InboxControl control = new UC_InboxControl(row, uC_Inbox);
    if (uC_Inbox.mnuUnreadChat.IsChecked == false)
    {
          inboxControlCollection.Add(control);
    }
    else
    {
          inboxUnreadOnlyControlCollection.Add(control);
    }
}
```

What is the best approach to update UI in UI thread without hangs or freeze?

Comment: Why are you starting a new task inside Getdata()? Please post the full code.

Comment: inside RetriveData there are UI operations that by i used new task for UI update

Comment: Where are there UI operations in GetData? This makes no sense. All UI operations will freeze the UI thread.

Comment: Inside GetData first i request to server and get data from server.. After this i convert the JSON data to DATASET and after that i call "RetriveData" method and inside "RetriveData" ... i update my observationcollection variable

Comment: And what is MainFrame.Current?

Comment: You should update the data-bound Collection when the task t has finished.

Comment: MainFrame.Current is TaskScheduler object inside MainWindow

Comment: @mm8 you mean After Tasks t complete then i start a new task for UI Update?

Comment: No. You update the collection on the UI thread once the task has finished.

Comment: mm8 sorry but i dont undserstand ... how i get Data after Task t finish ? should i use event inside GetData ?

Comment: Use the ContinueWith method. See my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142477/discussion-between-ankur-tripathi-and-mm8).

Comment: You can use `!uC_Inbox.mnuUnreadChat.IsChecked` instead of `uC_Inbox.mnuUnreadChat.IsChecked == false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `GetData` method should not access any UI elements. It should be executed on a background thread and return a list of objects that you want to display in the view. You could then use the `ContinueWith` method to populate the `ObservableCollection` with these objects back on the UI thread, e.g.:

```
Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    return GetData(true);  // <-- GetData should return a collection of objects
}).ContinueWith(task =>
{
    //that you add to your ObservableCollection here:
    foreach (var item in task.Result)
        yourObservableCollection.Add(item);
},
System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

The same result can be achieved with `async/await`, which will restore the UI context after completing the task:

```
// await the task itself, after that do the UI stuff
var collection = await Task.Run(() =>
{
    // directly call the retrieve data
    return RetriveData(tempDataSet, firstTime);
});

// this code will resume on UI context
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    var control = new UC_InboxControl(row, uC_Inbox);
    if (!uC_Inbox.mnuUnreadChat.IsChecked)
    {
        inboxControlCollection.Add(control);
    }
    else
    {
        inboxUnreadOnlyControlCollection.Add(control);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I call the `RetriveData` directly here. Also you can mark it as `async` too, so you can do:

```
public async Task<> GetData(...)
{
    // some code ...
    return await Task.Run(() => 
    {
        return RetriveData(tempDataSet, firstTime));
    }
}
```

To achieve this you need to mark the method as `async`. If it is a event handler, you can use `async void`, in other case use `async Task`.